# How can I display kind="swarm" and kind="point" on the same catplot in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, catplot

I am trying to display both the means and errors (kind="point") and individual data points (kind="swarm") overlayed on the same catplot in Seaborn.

I have the following code:

```
sns.catplot(x="Variable_A", y="Dependent_Variable", col="Variable_B", data=LRP_df, kind="swarm", color = "black")

sns.catplot(x="Variable_A", y="Dependent_Variable", col="Variable_B", data=LRP_df, kind="point", color = "red")

sns.despine()
```

which produces the plots separately:

[image: result of calling catplot]

How can I make the two plots sit on the same axes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a face grid, you can overlay each one by specifying each one with map_dataframe(). The examples in this [official reference](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid) have been modified. The data is based on sample data.

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style="ticks")
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

g = sns.FacetGrid(exercise, col="kind")
g.map_dataframe(sns.stripplot, x="time", y="pulse", color="black")
g.map_dataframe(sns.pointplot, x="time", y="pulse", color="red")
g.set_axis_labels("time", "pulse")
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer